# ui:repeat inside a javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, el

is there any way to perform a ui:repeat inside a javascript? this is what i'm trying to do.

```
var point;
<ui:repeat value="#{testController.allItems}" var="item">
  point = new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude,item.longitude);
  createMarker(point, item.name, item.desc);   
</ui:repeat>
```

`testController.allItems` returns a list of entities with latitude and longitude and other values, i'm trying to do a store locator using google maps. `createMarker` adds marker to the map.

or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Consider adding a simple REST service and just fetch the data and parse it in js. The approach that you're implementing is extremely disgusting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try(another option: `c:forEach`):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
                var point;
                <ui:repeat value="#{s9.list}" var="item">
                   point = new google.maps.LatLng(#{item.latitude},#{item.longitude});
                   createMarker(point, #{item.name}, #{item.desc});
                </ui:repeat>
        </script>
```

If your function require String parameter, you should use '', for ex:

```
    google.maps.LatLng('#{item.latitude}','#{item.longitude}');
    createMarker(point, '#{item.name}', '#{item.desc}');
```

Comment: If you're generating _javascript_ code with _java_ code, it is better to move it to a JSF composite component. It is a more reusable practice. You can look [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html) and this [BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359042/execute-javascript-from-a-composite-component) example. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue (c:forEach would not work either). Using the `<h:outputScript>` tag instead of the `<script>` tag resolved the problem. With the `<h:outputScript>` tag I could use ui:repeat