# How I can add a media player with several source mp3

Tags: jsf, primefaces, media

I am looking for a mechanism to display a media player with multiple sources MP3 (attached image).

[image]

Using primefaces there is the tag:

```
<p:media value="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Mozart%20-%20Presto.mp3" width="200" height="20" player="quicktime" />
```

But it allows to have only one piece at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I've had good results with [Wikplayer](http://www.wikplayer.com/).  It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's completely client-side (ie: JavaScript) and continues playing as you change pages on the site.  And yes, it does allow multiple files.

For example, the default settings produces the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wikplayer.com/code.js" data-config=" ... " ></script>
```

The contents of `data-config` is:

```
{
  'skin': 'skins/wikfull/funkyBlue/skin.css',
  'volume': 50,
  'autoplay': false,
  'shuffle': false,
  'repeat': 0,
  'showcomment': false,
  'marqueetexton': true,
  'placement': 'top',
  'showplaylist': false,
  'playlist': [
    {
      'title': '(SAMPLE)%20Canon%20in%20D%20-%20Pachelbel',
      'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DMK6heUdRr-E'
    }
  ]
}
```

It's pretty obvious what most of these settings do, and to add more tracks all you have to do is add more objects the the `playlist` array, specifying the `title` and `url` as URL encoded parameters each time.

Comment: I have the title and the URL stored in the database, it has been there a way to generate it using your method? or is it static?

Comment: You can create the playlist  'javascript' part in a facelets page. Just search for javascript EL in stackoverflow. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410221/uirepeat-inside-a-javascript

Comment: I think I found the solution for your proposal. I generated a string that represents a JSON stream and I will place it directly into the script.
The script will generate this:
[
{'title', 'Title0', 'url': url 0 '},
{'title', 'Title1', 'url': url 2 '},
{'title', 'Title2', 'url': url 3 '}
]

Answer (score 0):

I share with you the solution I found

in the bean I generate a JSON string like this :

```
@ManagedBean public class AudioBean {

private String json = "[{'title':'MUSIC CALME','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DMK6heUdRr-E'},"
        + "         {'title':'Selena Gomez - Come & Get It','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-D1EB74Ckg&list=RDn-D1EB74Ckg'},"
        + "     {'title':'Demi Lovato - Heart Attack','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AByfaYcOm4A&index=3&list=RDn-D1EB74Ckg'}]";

public String getJson() {
    return json;
}

public void setJson(String json) {
    this.json = json;
} }
```

and in the XHTML page I call the json attribut by El Expression :

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wikplayer.com/code.js"
    data-config="{'skin':'skins/wikfull/ribbonRed/skin.css','volume':62,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':true,'repeat':0,'showcomment':false,'marqueetexton':true,'placement':'top','showplaylist':false,
    'playlist':
        #{audioBean.json}
}">
</script>
```