# Read several mp3 files in JSF page

Tags: jsf, audio, primefaces, mp3

I use JSF 2.2 + primefaces.

I want to add a Component that allows me to play list of mp3 files.
for example, I have a folder that contains a lot of mp3 file and I would like to have a component to play them in jsf pages like this picture

[image]

I found [wikiplayer](http://wikplayer.com) but when I load a page it generate an iframe  where he puts the content of my jsf page, which means when I load the page by running a query, it's just the iframe to reload not the wikplayer. 
the wikplayer loads if I click F5 or refresh the page the browser button, the code generated is look like 
[image]

Comment: What happened here? I helped answering an **identical** question less than two months ago...  This is weird since that question is not there anymore.

Comment: @Kukeltje: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299263/how-i-can-add-a-media-player-with-several-source-mp3 It has the same screenshot, but the technical question is a bit different.

Comment: YES, but it does not show up in google when using 'mp3 jsf primefaces stackoverflow'...  Not even when I include 'kukeltje'.  Hmmm maybe I should have tried search IN stackoverflow

Comment: yes @Kukeltje it's same but not the same technical question, 
the wikplayer is not work for me, because it not refreshed when i send a request (when i send request the wikiplayer would have the new response generated by query but it not refreshed because he place my jsf code in a iFrame, and juste iFrame was refreshed not the player)

Comment: Referencing the other post with a lot of detailed info about the 'inner workings' of wikiplayer helps a lot when others try to answer the question

Comment: Please no screenshots of code. Add it inline please

Comment: it juste the code generated when i add wikplayer , just see 2 iFrame genrated